# how to use glad.h and glew.h at the same time?

Tags: opengl, include

My opengl version is 4.0 and use glad3.3. 
I want to use `glTexEnvi()`, but only glad4.6 support this function and I can't use it. When I include both glad.h and glew.h, there was an error(`error C1189:#error:gl.h included before glew.h`). 
So how can I use glad.h and glew.h at the same time? or is there another solution to use `glTexEnvi()`? 
Anyone help?

Comment: Thanks. I download the compatibility version and it works now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't. [Glad](https://glad.dav1d.de/) and [GLEW](http://glew.sourceforge.net/) are both OpenGL loaders.  Both do the same thing; they provide OpenGL function binding. Use either one or the other.

[`glTextEnv`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glTexEnv.xml) is a legacy OpenGL function. It is only provided in an compatibility profile [OpenGL Context](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Context) (respectively OpenGL 1.x and 2.x) and OpenGL ES 1.0.
Thus `glTexEnv` is not available in a core profile context, OpenGL ES 2.0 and OpenGL 3.x.

See [OpenGL specification - Khronos OpenGL registry](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/index_gl.php) and [OpenGL ES Specification - Khronos OpenGL ES Registry](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/index_es.php)

You have to use a **compatibility** profile OpenGL 3.3 Context. Ensure that the profile type is "compatibility" when you generate the OpenGL loader files, then `glTexEnvi` is defined.

---

[Glad](https://glad.dav1d.de/) is a loader generator. You have to specify the OpenGL (ES) version, for your target environment. Glad generates an API, which provides exactly the available instruction set for the specified environment respectively OpenGL (ES) verison. If an instruction does not "exist" in the header file, then it is not supported by the specified version.

In compare GLEW provides all OpenGL functionality is in a single header file. You have to care if a function is supported by the OpenGL context.